# How to return if an Array is empty in JSON output

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, null

I have an API endpoint which returns in JSON. If a user has many friends it will return an Array consisting of user's friend names but if a user doesn't have any friends then it return NULL.

The weird problem is-- in JSON:

```
[].length //returns 1
```

Output from GraphQL endpoint:

```
{
  "data": {
    "users": {
      "friends": null
     }
  }
}


console.log(JSON.stringify(resultJSON)); // displays []
```

So how do i check if the field returns NUll or not?

Comment: I’m not sure where you’re getting that 1 from: `JSON.parse('[]').length === [].length === 0`

Comment: I'm using GraphQL for API. So it returns in JSON. I'm honestly confounded that it returns 1 from an empty Array.

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include the raw JSON of a typical response?

Comment: Do you have control over that API?  It would be much easier to work with if having no friend returned an empty array.

Comment: Yes. I implemented that endpoint myself. but graphql  is very stringly typed language. I have an Array of objects as a return value there. Cant change that.

Comment: if that object is the "output" then `resultJSON` is not that object. There is no way this `console.log(JSON.stringify(resultJSON));` produces `[]` on that "output" shown. Please update with actual response and some code.